# Array List Iterator for Binary File Question

Tags: java, iterator, hex

Currently, I am coding a rudimentary hex editor in Java. The portion I have completed is as followed:

The user types in a Byte position that they would like to navigate to within the binary file that gets loaded. It first reads in the file and then stores it using an AList. Here is the code:

```
System.out.println("Enter name of file: ");
    String filename = in.nextLine();
    File file = new File(filename);
    if (file.exists()) {
        System.out.println(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
        System.out.println("Size: " + file.length() + " bytes.");
        System.out.println("Attempting to record file to AList");
        AList<Byte> fileList = new AList<>(); 
        raf.seek(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < raf.length(); i++) {
            fileList.add(raf.readByte());
        }
```

Now, my requirements also tell me to give the first 5 bytes before AND the 5 bytes after the position the user specifies. I think my logic is correct in terms of asking the user their desired byte position, but I'm not entirely certain. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
System.out.print("Enter byte positon to navigate to: ");
        long pos = in.nextLong();
        in.nextLine();
        ListIterator<Byte> itr = fileList.listIterator(0);
        int i = 0;
```

So what this SHOULD do is take in the byte position the user specifies and store it.

**The Problem**

I'm not sure how to iterate through this file. I would like to have the iterator start at that pos the user specifies and then construct two loops that make calls for previous (5 times) and then next (5 times) but I'm not entirely sure on how to do that. Can anyone give me an idea of where to start to construct this portion of my code? If anything is wrong, feel free to tell me and if you would like more of the code I can happily provide it :).

Comment: AList from https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ark/pj2/doc/edu/rit/util/AList.html?

Comment: Do you have to use a List?  Storing every byte of a file as a java.lang.Byte reference will literally require several times the amount of storage as the file itself uses.  A [MappedByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map%28java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,long,long%29) would probably work well here.

Comment: I have to use a list :/